# Firebase Realtime IOS can't read data permission denied

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is the error in the console

> Unable to get latest value for query FQuerySpec (path: /Oeuvres/13, params: {
> }), client offline with no active listeners and no matching disk cache entries
>
> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB082010] Got data message: {
> b =     {
> d = "Permission denied";
> s = "permission_denied";
> };
> r = 3; }

When I run my code

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("Oeuvres").child(id).getData(completion:  { error, snapshot in

      guard error == nil else {
        print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return;
      }
        print(snapshot.value)
    });
```

Here's my rules on firebase realtime database

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in the question but we don't know what the `id` var resolves to and whether or not you're authenticated. Please update the question with details. Also, there's no reason to `guard` the error as you won't be using it after that. `if let error = error` is probably a better option.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but was finally able to solve it after reading the full error lol. In my case, since I was using sorting/filtering queries prior to my `.getData()`, I needed to add the appropriate indexes in my Rules.